# Issue while connecting to mongodb atlas with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am a beginner to mongodb and in my project i have started to use mongodb Atlas . Though i have whitelisted my IP address  it still says please whitelist . I have not included any routing in my project , its a basic connection to db which i am trying to do . When i used a command to whitelist my IP in ubuntu i got an Error saying

sachin@sachin-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/DevConnector$ node server
Server started at 5000
**connection timed out**

Can anyone help me out

Comment: you need to allow IP in mongodb Atlas

Comment: Can you provide more details? the code you use? how to recreate the issue?
Anyway I would suggest to temporary whitelist all IPs (0.0.0.0), and check if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just white list your from MongoDB Atlas website.

1. Go to MongoDB website.
2. Sign in.
3. Then go to Network Access in Security.
4. Then add your IP to whitelist it.
   [Screenshot of MongoDB Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGtA8.png)